how we can add 2 sql queries in a single dag
export_query: sql_query1 ;
export_query_filter: ""
processing_modules:

'export_bqtobqtmp_task'
'export_bqtmptogcs_task'
'pre_shell_execution'
'post_shell_execution'

processing_dependencies:

'start >> generate_hashid >> export_bqtobqtmp_task >> export_bqtmptogcs_task >> pre_shell_execution >> post_shell_execution >> bq_delete_target_export_table >> end'

want to run sql_query1 first , if the result is expected then proceed for sql_query2

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You could use a BranchPythonOperator to the get the result of the query1 using a xcom and make the decision with the result .
You need to make sure to push this value in query_1 task to a xcom. (it`ll depends on your operator that will run the query.)
def _decision_task(**context) -> str:
    ti = context['ti'].xcom_pull(task_ids='query_1', key='return_value')
    returned_values = ((base64.b64decode(ti).decode('utf-8')))
    returned_values = decoded_databases.split("\n")

    if returned_values:
        return 'next_task'

    else: #U could live without this return and it`ll just skip the 
`next_task`
        return 'dummy_task'

checks = BranchPythonOperator(
    task_id="decision_task",
    python_callable=_decision_task,
    provide_context=True,
)



with DAG(
......
) as dag:
    query_1 >> checks >> [next_task,dummy_task]

Or for Bigquery without xcom
def query_1(bq_client, **kwargs):
    sql =  ''' SELECT 1'''
    query_results = bq_client.query(sql)
    results = [row for row in (dict(row) for row in query_results)] #Do what u want with the result

    if len(results) > 0:
        return True


def _checks(**kwargs):
    bq_client = BigQueryHook(
        gcp_conn_id="bigquery_default", use_legacy_sql=False
    ).get_client(GCP_PROJECT_ID, "us")

    if query_1(bq_client):
        return "next_task"


checks = BranchPythonOperator(
    task_id="checks",
    python_callable=_checks,
    provide_context=True,
)



with DAG(
...
) as dag:
    checks >> next_task

